# Editar una categoría de un articulo en mi aplicacion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

estoy creando un blog app, pero tengo problemas con la categoría en la actualización del articulo.

**Cuando intento editar un articulo y su categoría mediante el check_box, esta no se actualiza.**

utilizo los modelos **article.rb**, **has_category.rb**, también **category.rb**, pero es en el archivo **has_category.rb** que hago la unión con los artículos del blog. También está el archivo **articles_controller.rb**

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
include AASM #Incluimos la maquina de estado
#para que nuestro modelo interactue con la gema.
    #La tabla
    #Campos
    #Escribir métodos
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    has_many :has_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :has_categories

    validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true #Valida que el elemento no esté vacío.
    validates :body, presence: true, length: {minimum: 20} 
    before_save :set_visits_count
    after_create :save_categories

    has_attached_file :cover, styles: { medium:"8000x8000", thumb:"300x200" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :cover, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    #Custom Setter
    #Metodo que permite asignar valor a un atributo de un objeto
    def categories=(value)
        @categories = value
    end

    def update_visits_count
        # self.save if self.visits_count.nil?
        self.update(visits_count: self.visits_count + 1)
    end

    aasm column: "state" do
        state :in_draft, initial: true
        state :published

        #creamos eventos

        event :publish do
            transitions from: :in_draft, to: :published
        end

        event :unpublish do
            transitions from: :published, to: :in_draft
        end
    end

    #private

    def save_categories
        #raise @categories.to_yaml
        @categories.each do |category_id|
            HasCategory.create(category_id: category_id, article_id: self.id)
        end
    end

    def set_visits_count
        self.visits_count ||= 0
    end
end
```

**has_category.rb**

```
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :category
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
#
before_action :authenticate_user!#, except: [:show,:index]
before_action :set_article, except:[:index,:new,:create]
before_action :authenticate_editor!, only: [:new,:create,:update]
before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:destroy]
#GET /articles
def index
#Puede acceder desde la vista o controlador, sin inaccesibles.
@articles = Article.where(state: "published") #todos los registros de la tabla article
end

#GET /articles/:id
def show
    @article.update_visits_count
    @comment = Comment.new
end

#GET /articles/new
def new
    @article = Article.new #Aun no esta en la base de datos
    #@categories = Category.all
end

def edit
end     

#POST /articles
def create
    #INSERT INTO
    @article = current_user.articles.new(article_params)
    @article.categories = params[:categories]
    if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
else 
    render :new
end
end

#DELETE /articles/:id
def destroy 
    #DELETE FROM articles
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy # Destroy eliminar el objeto de la BD
    redirect_to articles_path
end

#PUT /article/:id
def update
    # UPDATE
    if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
    #if @article.update(article_params)
    #redirect_to @article
else
    render :edit
end
end

private

def set_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
private

def validate_user
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: "necesitas iniciar sesión"
end
private 
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title,:body,:cover,:categories)
end
end
```

Form article

```
<div class="field">
<%= check_box_tag "categories[]", category.id %> <%= category.name %>
</div>
 <%end%>
```

Comment: Pero no has explicado cual es tu problema o error que tienes

Comment: Cuando intento editar un articulo y su categoría mediante el check_box, esta no se actualiza..

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar:

```
<%= check_box_tag "categories[]", category.id %> <%= category.name %>
```

por

```
<%= check_box_tag "category_ids[]", category.id %> <%= category.name %>
```

También en tu controlador cambia:

```
params.require(:article).permit(:title,:body,:cover,:category_ids)
```

por

```
params.require(:article).permit(:title,:body,:cover, category_ids: [])
```

Si esto no resuelve tu problema, agrega a tu pregunta la información de log que te muestra cuando tratas de actualizar un artículo.